# importing firebase to react-native

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to use the firebase in a react native project

I installed the firebase in my project:

```
npm install --save firebase
```

and I'm importing it into my app.js

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {

  render() {
    return (
      <View >
        <Text>Testando Firebase</Text>    
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

and then the error is displayed:

> Objects are not valida as a react child (found: object with
>   keys{&&typeof, type, key, ref, props, _owner, _store}). If you meant
>   to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

but when I remove the import from firebase, the app works perfectly.

Comment: It's weird, I try it in expo https://snack.expo.io/r1tb9Mhlm and no error. By the way, to use `firebase` you need add some more firebase config for your app

Comment: Your import is wrong, it should be ```import firebase from 'firebase'```. However, the error message doesn't seem to be related to it. If changing the import doesn't solve the issue, we can check for further errors

Comment: Apparently this is all right but it does not work, so I removed the firebase and installed a previous version npm install --save firebase@5.0.3, now works perfectly

Comment: I would appreciate that if you accept the answer!

Answer (score 6):

Try to install the version 5.0.2. Use this command as administrator:

```
npm uninstall firebase    
npm install --save firebase@5.0.2
```

As far as i see, the current version (5.0.4) is buggy!

Answer (score 0):

You need to import as follow

import * as firebase from 'firebase';

You first must have firebase installed.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to uninstall the current version of Firebase and install an older version.

1st step `npm uninstall firebase`

2nd step `npm i firebase@8.0.3`

It was the version that worked for my case.